# Saving a user in CakePHP with ACL group name specified rather than group id

Tags: cakephp

I have set up a Cake 2.3.1 app with ACL following [this tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html) so I have a users table and a groups table.

Everything is working fine, but I'm a little confused about how I should go about saving new users since I don't want the user to be able to select their own group. The group will be chosen based on a number of things that the user inputs on the form so it will be determined by conditional statements in the controller.

At the moment I'm doing this:

`$this->request->data['User']['group_id'] = '2';` (or 1, 3 or 4 depending on conditional statements in the controller).

Then, I'm doing a save on `$this->data`. This works but I'd like to be able to specify the group **name** rather than hardcode the id so that when we move to production and clear the database, it won't matter if the groups are added in a different order.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm aware that I can do a lookup on the name and find the ID but I was wondering if there was a way of getting Cake to do this without me explicitly specifying it.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of doing this.

The first I haven't tried, but it would be to change the primary key of the group table to the name of the group and set the primaryKey variable in the Group model and all subsequent reference and associations with this table in all the other models. That would probably bring you more than a headache and I wouldn't recommend it because you'd probably break the ACL component one way or another.

The other way is what I'd do, and it requires a bit of programming on your part (Cake doesn't have an easy way of doing this that I know of).
In the User model, put a beforeSave and in that function, create a dummy variable with the group name, do the lookup of the name and insert the correct id, and delete that variable.

On User.ctp model

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['group_name'])) {
        //do the lookup with the group_name
        $group = $this->Group->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('name'=>$this->data[$this->alias]['group_name'])));
        if (count($group) <= 0)
           //... throw an Exception or handle any way you want this case

        $real_group_id = $group['Group']['id'];
        $this->data[$this->alias]['group_id'] = $real_group_id;
        unset($this->data[$this->alias]['group_name']);
    }

    return true; //remember this is important! otherwise the save will stop
}
```

When you want to change the user's group or add another user, just do this in the controller
   `$data_to_save['User']['group_name'] = 'webuser';`
and the beforeSave function will take care of the rest.

I realize you asked for a Cake-easy-way of doing this, but I guess there's none (not sure though, feel free to correct me), the beforeSave function could save you a lot of repetitive code on the controllers. The only thing you'd have to be careful when clearing the database or changing group ids is to reassociate them correctly with the users already in the database, but since is a "moving to production" change, those users already predefined should be few or none.